# Persist view state with jQuery and servlets

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a web application which has tons of divs containing modules (JSP fragments). The site is written in plain JSP/servlets/jQuery. In an ideal situation, the user only uses the buttons to navigate through the site, and ajax loads the modules in the corresponding divs. However, if the user reloads the site, or gets a server side validation error + redirect, the view goes into default mode where he started, and I'd have to reconstruct the state he last seen.

With low module count I've introduced variables to track the state of each div, which worked fine, however when it reached a higher complexity, it started to be a big pain, and it's going to be worse, plus a nightmare to maintain and debug.

E.g.: there is `<div id="one">`, `<div id="two">` and `<div id="tree">`. If one is active, two and three is hidden. If two is active, one is dimmed, three is hidden. If three is active, one and two is active as well, but not showing the same content like they would when they were active. Even this example is really complicated, and not even counting that each input change (search, filter, etc.) can trigger these transitions.

Is there any conventional way or some kind of trick to make this easier?

Comment: I see, but I'd appreciate an ajax example which would be acceptable at any company, rather my hack and slash js code which is watching tens of variables.

Comment: Could you post a jdfiddle with three div that are working well as you say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple way to save the states :

```
<div id="1" class="persist" state='visisble'></div>
<div id="2" class="persist" state='visisble'></div>
<div id="3" class="persist" state='hidden'>
    <input type="text" class="persist" id="i1" />
</div>
```

Using JQuery, I would select every div with persist class. Create a JSON (o other) like :

```
{
    persistance [
       { 'id':1, 'state':'visible' },
       { 'id':2, 'state':'visible' },
       { 'id':3, 'state':'hidden', 
          "fields":[ { 'id':'i1', value:'foo' }] 
       }
}
```

It will contain every data you want to keep (hope you have naming convention here ;) ). For each divs, get the inputs/... with the persistant class to store the value (or other field name depending on the tag)

Then send it to the server to keep it (or do what you want with it). To restore the states, you have the ID to set everything back to previously. For each div id, set the value receive and for each field too.

You run that with the beforeunload page event (not sure if it work fine ;) ) to save it. To restore it, you either use the same way with Ajax and Jquery or diretly in JSP.

For code example, you will need to give me some more info (class for your module, type of data needed, ...)

Comment: You are welcome, this should be quite effective even with a lot of module. I have no idea if this exist in a Library somewhere, if not, this should ;)